# Search for string (variable match) and print

Tags: php, string, variables, search

I want to search for a number in text from `DB` and print them. Numbers are product codes and vary from 4 to 6 digits.

Example:

```
aaaaa 1234 aaaa
aaaaa 123456 aaaaa
aaaaa 12345 aaaaa
```

What I got is an array with exact match of 5 numbers, but not varying and not printing:

```
$string = $sql['products_description'];
preg_match_all('/(?<![0-9])[0-9]{5}(?![0-9])/', $string, $match);
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   echo $match[$i];
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Any help?

edit:
I got this working closely:

```
$string = $sql['products_description'];
preg_match_all('#\d{4,6}#', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  print_r($match);
}
```

but returns something like:

> Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => 123456 [2] => 12345 )

I need them purely (not in an array) because I have to use each number separately later. In this case, how to extract each element and print it?

SOLUTION:

```
$var = array();
preg_match_all('#\d{4,6}#', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
$var[] = $match;
}

for ($i=0; $i<=count($matches[0]); $i++) {
  for ($j=0; $j<=count($matches[0]); $j++) {
    if (($var[$i][$j]) != '') {
      print_r($var[$i][$j]);
      echo '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my query is correct, show me product description with number inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that they are between 4 and 6 long:

```
$string = $sql['products_description'];
preg_match_all('#\d{4,6}#', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  echo $match;
}
```

I only modified the pattern and the for-loop.

Edit if you want it "purely":

```
$string = $sql['products_description'];
$var = array();
preg_match_all('#\d{4,6}#', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  $var[] = $match;
}
```

Comment: Close. I modified this but still not working. This one prints something like Array ( [0] => 1500 [1] => 30459 [2] => 30458 ) and I want them purely, not in an array.

Comment: Do you want them comma separated as I don't completely understand what you mean with "purely".

Comment: The edition returns only the word "Array". I meant "purely" like printing numbers one by one or available to put into a $var. e.g. $var[$i]=$matches[$i]; --> $var1=1234 / $var2=123456 , etc ... If print them separately I can also use as a $var.

Comment: See my latest update in the bottom code, this way you can use the $var for printing also outside the for-loop. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Well, I can't see it working. I tried to print with echo $var[]; but nothing.

Comment: `$var` will be an array containing all the digits. If you want to print an array you have to use something like `print_r($var)` or `var_dump($var)`. If you post more code where you actually process the values I could help you further.

Comment: Kenny, I wrote the solution on my post but you helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Closest answer! Full solution on my post! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Edit:

```
preg_match_all('/[456]/', $str, $matches);
$var = implode('', $matches[0]);
print_r($var)
```

Comment: no, I want matches from 4 to 6 numbers and print them purely (not in an array)

Answer (score 1):

```
     preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
     print_r($matches);
     $digit=$matches[0][0];
     $digit=(int)$digit;
     echo $digit;
```

You will get ur number this way..

**Edit#1**

---

```
  print_r($matches[0]);
  //Output :
        Array
          (
            [0] => 1234,
            [1] => 123456,
            [2] => 1234


           )
  echo implode("",$matches[0]);
    //Output: 12341234561234
```

---

**Edit#2**

---

```
   $var1=$matches[0][0];
   $var2=$matches[0][1];
   $var3=$matches[0][2];
```

Comment: still not working properly, it returns only the first number like 1234

Comment: @KelsonBatista What is in your $str variable..?

Comment: $str = $sql['products_description']; --> returns something like "blablabla 1234 blablabla 123456 blablabla 12345 blablabla"

Comment: @KelsonBatista So you want to strip all digit? like you want '123412345612345' from your returns ?

Comment: Actually I need '1234', '123456' and '12345'.

Comment: @KelsonBatista Please recheck.

Comment: I need them separated to put into a $var each one, not inline.

Comment: I wrote the solution on my post but you helped me a lot! Thank you!